# Is the product of two Sobolev functions in L^p?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Assume that $f\in W^{\alpha-1,p}(R^n)$ with  $0<\alpha<1$ and $p>2n/\alpha$.

Given another function $ g\in W^{\beta,p}(R^n)$ with $\beta>0$.

Under what conditions on $\beta$ can we get that $fg\in L^p(R^n)$?

Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks! The problem here is that the function $f$ is in the Sobolev space with negative index. So sobolev embedding theorems seems not to be helpful.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I noticed that afterwards and so deleted my comment.

Comment: Not sure how is $fg$ defined: by duality, $(fg,\phi):=(f,g\phi)$? Even if $g$ is infinitely smooth (say, $g(x)=\exp(-|x|^2)$), $fg$ need not be any more regular than $f$: $fg \in L^p$ would mean $|(fg,\phi)|\le C\|\phi\|_q$, that is, $|(f,g\phi)|\le C\|g^{-1}g\phi\|_q$, and so $f\in L^p(|g(x)|^pdx)$.

Comment: Note that even if $g$ is smooth, rapidly decaying, and equal to $1$ on an open set, it's hard to imagine a reasonable condition for $fg$ to be in $L^p$, except that $f$ is already in $L^p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering whether it is meaningful in the Bony paraproducts sense ?